# Issue when porting from OpenGL 1.1 to OpenGL-ES 2.0

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

this is  my opengl-es 2.0 code :

```
{
    for (surfnum=0;surfnum<surftotal;surfnum++){
        for (i=0;i<triNum[surfnum];i++){
            GLfloat *Vertices[] = { triArray[surfnum][i].normpt1,  triArray[surfnum][i].normpt2,triArray[surfnum][i].normpt3};
            glGenBuffers(1, &ui32Vbo);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ui32Vbo);
            unsigned int uiSize = 3 * (sizeof(GLfloat) * 1); 
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiSize,*Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        }
    }
}
for(int i = 0; i < 80000; ++i)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    int i32Location = glGetUniformLocation(uiProgramObject, "projmatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv( i32Location, 1, GL_FALSE, pfIdentity);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ARRAY, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,i);
    eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);
}
```

This is my opengl-es 2.0 code . I was working on opengl 1.1 in which i was able to show the iso surface form data .

This is my Opengl 1.1 code:

```
void drawTriangle()
{
    int surfnum, i;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(0,0.6,0.1);


    for (surfnum=0;surfnum<surftotal;surfnum++)
    {
        for (i=0;i<triNum[surfnum];i++)
                {
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glNormal3fv(triArray[surfnum][i].normpt1);
            glVertex3fv(triArray[surfnum][i].pt1);
            glNormal3fv(triArray[surfnum][i].normpt2);
            glVertex3fv(triArray[surfnum][i].pt2);
            glNormal3fv(triArray[surfnum][i].normpt3);
            glVertex3fv(triArray[surfnum][i].pt3);
            glEnd();
            glFlush();
            glutSwapBuffers();
        }
    }
}
```

I am not getting the same result as I was getting in opengl , in opengl-es 2.0 also a

> warning coming like: libegl: use software fallback ;
>       output occurs very slowly
>       here the output goes out of window

If you want an other information ask me.

Comment: This looks correct for an orthographic projection matrix.  What is happening, and what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't make sense.

```
{
    for (surfnum=0;surfnum<surftotal;surfnum++){
        for (i=0;i<triNum[surfnum];i++){
            GLfloat *Vertices[] = { triArray[surfnum][i].normpt1,  triArray[surfnum][i].normpt2,triArray[surfnum][i].normpt3};
            glGenBuffers(1, &ui32Vbo);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ui32Vbo);
            unsigned int uiSize = 3 * (sizeof(GLfloat) * 1); 
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiSize,*Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        }
    }
}
```

Are you actually creating a buffer object for each triangle? Well, you're not even doing that, because you only have a buffer object for each set of 3 floats, which isn't even a full *triangle*. I can only assume that this is a vertex position. You keep calling `glGenBuffers` in the middle of this loop, so it will dutifully generate another buffer object. Creating too many buffer objects may be why you're hitting software fallbacks.

Also, doesn't `normpt1` contain the normal, not the position?

And then there's this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 80000; ++i)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    int i32Location = glGetUniformLocation(uiProgramObject, "projmatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv( i32Location, 1, GL_FALSE, pfIdentity);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ARRAY, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,i);
    eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);
}
```

First, you didn't glBindBuffer your buffer object. Yes, I know it is still bound from before, but it's always good to be explicit about these things.

Most importantly, what is this: `glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0,i);`? Isn't `i` the array index? The third parameter needs to be the number of vertices to draw. And GL_TRIANGLES will fail unless this value is divisible by 3.

But that doesn't matter, since the buffer object you last created only has enough room for 1 vertex. So it is *impossible* to render from.