# problem in rendering triangles in Opengl-es 2.0

Tags: c++, c, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem when going from opengl 1.1 to Opengl-es 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501458/problem-when-going-from-opengl-1-1-to-opengl-es-2-0)

I am trying to render an isosurface by drawing triangles which takes its data from a text file and render it using opengl-es 2.0 . I was able to do it in Opengl 1.1 but because in opengl-es 2.0 some functions are not present so I am getting difficulty in  buffer or may be some other problem I am actually not able to understand . I am pasting my both draw triangle code opengl and opengl-es 2.0 . Can you tell me why is am not able to get the same result . i am doing coding in ubuntu 10.10 with the use of pvrsdk.

OpenGL-ES 2.0 code :

```
    for (surfnum=0;surfnum<surftotal;surfnum++)
    {
        glClearColor(0.6f, 0.8f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        for (i=0;i<triNum[surfnum];i++)
        {
            GLfloat *Vertices[] = {    
                            triArray[surfnum][i].pt1, 
                            triArray[surfnum][i].pt2,
                            triArray[surfnum][i].pt3
                        };


            glGenBuffers(1, &ui32Vbo);
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ui32Vbo);
            unsigned int uiSize = 3 * (sizeof(GLfloat) * 3); 
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiSize,*Vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 8000; ++i)
        {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            int i32Location = glGetUniformLocation(uiProgramObject, "projmatrix");
            glUniformMatrix4fv( i32Location, 1, GL_FALSE, projmatrix);
            glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
            glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ARRAY, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
            //glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, triNum[surfnum], GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,Vertices);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,triNum[surfnum]);
            eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface);
        }
    }
```

same thing I have done it in OpenGL :
OpenGL code :

```
for (surfnum=0;surfnum<surftotal;surfnum++)
{
    for (i=0;i<triNum[surfnum];i++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        glVertex3fv(triArray[surfnum][i].pt1);
        glVertex3fv(triArray[surfnum][i].pt2);
        glVertex3fv(triArray[surfnum][i].pt3);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
}
```

surfnum , vertex_array , surftotal are defined variables.
Also i am getting a result but not the same for both and I am also getting a warnig :
libegl : software fallback

P.S = here if I try to get first all the vertices and then try to bind it in a single buffer then it gives segmentation fault . May be I am doing that wrong . If thats a correct way you can tell me to how to do that .
If you want any other information tell me.

HI christian as you said that I can do this without using glmapbuffer I try to do that but it still gives me error:

```
glGenBuffers(surftotal, uiVBO);
{
    for(surfnum=0; surfnum<surftotal; ++surfnum)
    {
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBO[surfnum]);
            size_t buf_size = 9*sizeof(GLfloat)*triNum[surfnum];
            GLfloat* const pData = (GLfloat*)malloc(buf_size);
            for(i=0; i<triNum[surfnum]; ++i) {
                memcpy(pData+i*9,   triArray[surfnum][i].pt1, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
                memcpy(pData+i*9+3, triArray[surfnum][i].pt2, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
                memcpy(pData+i*9+6, triArray[surfnum][i].pt3, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
            }
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buf_size, pData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            free(pData);
    }   
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
    for(surfnum=0; surfnum<surftotal; ++surfnum)
    {
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBO[surfnum]);
            glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ARRAY, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3*triNum[surfnum]);
    }
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);        //clean up, of course      

}
```

thats the error I am getting while compiling the above program

> libEGL warning: use software fallback

Comment: How exactly is this code any different than the last time you asked this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501458/problem-when-going-from-opengl-1-1-to-opengl-es-2-0 . You still have the most of the same mistakes I pointed out in the answer I gave you: you create a bunch of buffer objects but never store any of them. You're still creating a buffer object per triangle for no particular reason. You pass the wrong value to `glDrawArrays` (granted this time, it's a different wrong value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, don't create a buffer in the drawing function (which is supposed to run often), but in some initialization code (e.g. after loading the data from file), as I suppose it won't change after loaded from the file (and if yes, then just update the buffer data). Second, don't make a buffer for every triangle, but a single one for all triangles (or maybe  `surftotal` buffers, one for each surface).

So first we create `surftotal` buffers, hopefully not in the draw routine:

```
GLuint uiVBO[surftotal];
glGenBuffers(surftotal, uiVBO);
```

Next we copy the data (only when it changed, maybe only once after loading, if that's the case, `GL_STATIC_DRAW` might be better). For each triangle we need to store the position data of its three vertices, making 9 floats per triangle (Your code is quite messed up, storing the addresses of the vertices or not even that). We will allocate storage for the buffer without giving it data and then map the buffer data to write directly into it. This way we don't need to allocate temporary CPU memory for our data ourselves (The driver will do that for us). Of course we unmap it after copying the data, so that the buffer can then be used for rendering:

```
for(surfnum=0; surfnum<surftotal; ++surfNum)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBO[surfnum]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 9*sizeof(GLfloat)*triNum[surfnum], NULL, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
    GLfloat *pData = glMapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_WRITE_ONLY);
    for(i=0; i<triNum[surfnum]; ++i,pData+=9)
    {
        mempcy(pData, triArray[surfnum][i].pt1, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
        mempcy(pData+3, triArray[surfnum][i].pt2, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
        mempcy(pData+6, triArray[surfnum][i].pt3, 3*sizeof(GLfloat));
    }
    glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
}
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);      //clean up behind us
```

When finally rendering the data, we bind the buffer, tell OpenGL to source the vertex data from it and render it (giving `glDrawArrays` the number of vertices and not triangles). Of course we do that for each surface:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(VERTEX_ARRAY);
for(surfnum=0; surfnum<surftotal; ++surfnum)
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBO[surfnum]);
    glVertexAttribPointer(VERTEX_ARRAY, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3*triNum[surfnum]);
}
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);        //clean up, of course
```

It may be a better idea to pack all surface's triangles into a single buffer to draw all surfaces with a single draw call. It may also be a good idea to consider indexed triangle sets using `glDrawElements` and the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`, but I suppose your data structure doesn't even have that information and you first should really understand how arrays and buffers work before complicating things even more (I hope my answer helps with that). Try to understand what each and every line of this answer code really does, querying other sources of documentation if needed. In general, don't learn such complex things like OpenGL or 3d graphics in general by staring at some code samples, but by some real documentation and learning resources, to really understand what you are doing.

Comment: I tried it but it says glMapBuffer, mempcy,  glUnmapBuffer is undeclared . then i found that in opengl-es 2.0 we use glMapBufferOES and we have to include file gl2ext.h but still its giving the same error of undeclared function

Comment: @Sudhanshu `memcpy` should be in `string.h` (C string library) (assuming you are using C/C++), but if this function is really new to you and you are using C/C++, then this could be a hint, that you should perhaps deepen your C/C++ skills before delving into 3d grahpics. I don't know if you have to do some additional stuff to use GL extension functions in ES (as I only have PC experience, and there you have to), but as `glBufferData` and the like are simply useable, it is strange that `glMapBuffer` is not.

Comment: @Sudhanshu Otherwise, just allocate your own temporary storage (with `malloc` or `new`) in the size of the buffer, fill it using the described loop, and copy the data directly in `glBufferData` (or `glBufferSubData` if the buffer already exists and doesn't need to change size).

Comment: I am doing this in PC not in ES so what additional stuff you are talking about , please elaborate me on that.

Comment: @Sudhanshu You have to query the driver for extension functions to get function pointers to these functions (either using wgl or glx, not sure about mac). But why use ES on a PC (as the question and the code is tagged ES)? I don't know if you really have to mess with extension function pointers in ES, even on a PC. If yes, take a look at [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Actually I don't have any mobile for ES implementation but I want to do work on OpenGl-ES 2.0 so the best way to use this on PC is by an Emulator so I used it . Thanks for your reply I will look at GLEW

Comment: i have changed the question please elaborate me on this I don't want to go on using extension files

Comment: @Sudhanshu The code looks correct at first sight. Remember to delete your buffers (using `glDeleteBuffers`) when you're finished with them. Otherwise if this code is in the render function you allocate new buffer memory every frame. Or, the better idea, move the buffer construction out of the render function! The warning means, that the driver uses software emulation, maybe something you use is not supported on your hardware or maybe its due to ES emulation, don't know.